# PostConstruct при constructor injecton

Tags: java, spring

Зачем нужно использовать @PostConstruct, когда используется инъекция в конструктор?

Правильно понимаю, что при инъекции в конструктор, впрыскиваемые бины уже проинициализированны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методы, аннотированные @PostConstruct вызываются, только один раз, сразу после инициализации свойств компонента. Т.е. вначале отрабатывает конструктор, затем метод, аннотированый @PostConstruct

Что касается второго вопроса. Вы должны позаботиться о том, чтобы в момент внедрения зависимостей "внедряемые бины" были проинициализированы, независимо от того, через что происходит инъекция (конструктор или метод)

Comment: Расскажите по второму вопросу. Что значит позаботиться, что бины проинициализированы в момент впрыскивания? Как это достигается?

Comment: Это означает что контейнер который реализует CDI и которым вы пользуетесь(эта та штука которая отвечает в том числе за инстанцирование контекста вашего приложения и без которой вы ничего не сделаете если используете DI) должен быть осведомлен обо всех компонентах контекста(объектах которые должны быть инстанцированы и внедрены(или не внедрены) в другие объекты). Достигнуто это может быть разными путями, xml, java-config, annotations или просто указанием на сканирование соответствующих пакетов и  инстанцированием чего попало. Зависит это от конкретной имплементации CDI.